# Connect to remote MS Access database from Linux Server using PHP

Tags: php, linux, windows, ms-access

Does anyone know if it's possible to connect and query an MS Access database from a Linux Server using PHP?

If it is possible I'm thinking install ODBC driver on the Linux server, but will it work to connect to Access is the question. I've read it's possible with MSSQL.

My knowledge is very limited when it comes to any Windows related DBs so any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. I've done it using [ODBTP](http://odbtp.sourceforge.net), which took advantage of the ODBC driver on the (Windows) machine that hosted the Access database file.

It's also theoretically possible to use an ODBC driver on the Linux server to read an Access database on a Windows networking share if the Linux box can "see" it. However, I've never had very good luck with Access ODBC on Linux so I wouldn't recommend spending too much time trying to get it working.

Comment: Thanks Gord appreciated.